# QGIS How can I get city labels to render largest cities first?

Tags: qgis

When I plot cities in QGIS, it chooses which to plot and which to leave out.  This layer also has the population.  Is it possible to make QGIS plot the larger cities first using population as its guide?

[image: SE Nebraska]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the labels tab of the layer styling panel you can set the **priority** of a label to be an expression (the yellow box below):

[image]

In this case I have set the "value" to be this expression:

```
CASE 
    WHEN  "type"  =  'City'  THEN 10 
    WHEN  "type"  =  'Town'  THEN 9
    ELSE 5
END
```

So that labels with a type "City" are drawn before "Town" which are before all the others. To make a priority based on population you could use something like:

```
log10("Population")
```

As priority is expecting a value between 0 and 10.0.